# Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_TAG

Tags: error-message, php, json

I'm running PHP 5.3.3, which the docs say is supported, but if I try to go to the main admin page or go to add a field, I'm getting an error: 
    Use of undefined constant JSON_HEX_TAG - assumed 'JSON_HEX_TAG'

Everything I'm finding online points to this being an outdated PHP issue, but thought I would check since I am running a supported version of PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely missing the PHP [JSON extension](https://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), which is a [requirement](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/requirements#required-php-extensions) to run Craft.